# Networkx: change the color of edges conditionally

Tags: python, networkx

Suppose I have a DiGraph `DG` that represents a minimum spanning tree just like the following. I would like to change the color of edges based on one condition.

```
cc = [('8k3aO-mPeyhbR5HUucA5aA', 'Hi10sGSZNxQH3NLyWSZ1oA'),
      ('8k3aO-mPeyhbR5HUucA5aA', 'bLbSNkLggFnqwNNzzq-Ijw'),
      ('8k3aO-mPeyhbR5HUucA5aA', 'nmdkHL2JKFx55T3nq5VziA'),
      ('8k3aO-mPeyhbR5HUucA5aA', '_BcWyKQL16ndpBdggh2kNA'), 
      ('8k3aO-mPeyhbR5HUucA5aA', 'CQUDh80m48xnzUkx-X5NAw'),
      ('8k3aO-mPeyhbR5HUucA5aA', 'wZPizeBxMAyOSl0M0zuCjg'),
      ('8k3aO-mPeyhbR5HUucA5aA', 'hWDybu_KvYLSdEFzGrniTw'),
      ('8k3aO-mPeyhbR5HUucA5aA', 'kS1MQHYwIfD0462PE61IBw'),
      ('8k3aO-mPeyhbR5HUucA5aA', 'HFECrzYDpgbS5EmTBtj2zQ'),
      ('RtGqdDBvvBCjcu5dUqwfzA', 'Xwnf20FKuikiHcSpcEbpKQ'),
      ('RtGqdDBvvBCjcu5dUqwfzA', 'bLbSNkLggFnqwNNzzq-Ijw'),
      ('RtGqdDBvvBCjcu5dUqwfzA', 'WG3w_73scm_JUWJ_3Lgn0Q'),
      ('P5bUL3Engv-2z6kKohB6qQ', 'Hi10sGSZNxQH3NLyWSZ1oA'),
      ('P5bUL3Engv-2z6kKohB6qQ', 'nzsv-p1O8gCfP3XijfQrIw'),
      ('P5bUL3Engv-2z6kKohB6qQ', 'm07sy7eLtOjVdZ8oN9JKag'),
      ('hWDybu_KvYLSdEFzGrniTw', 'U4INQZOPSUaj8hMjLlZ3KA'),
      ('8RcEwGrFIgkt9WQ35E6SnQ', 'wZPizeBxMAyOSl0M0zuCjg'),
      ('Xwnf20FKuikiHcSpcEbpKQ', 'CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw'),
      ('HFECrzYDpgbS5EmTBtj2zQ', 'Xj0O2l0bp633ebmG468aZw'),
      ('XYSDrIef7g4Gmp3lNFVO6A', 'wZPizeBxMAyOSl0M0zuCjg'),
      ('wZPizeBxMAyOSl0M0zuCjg', 'syvwUKQJ4OYfmL_ixVLMeQ')]
      DG = nx.DiGraph()
      DG.add_edges_from(cc)
      pos = nx.spring_layout(DG)
      plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
      nx.draw(DG, pos = pos,  arrows = False,
      node_color = 'black', width = 0.7, alpha = 0.9)
```

Notice that it is a graph of a minimum spanning tree. **I want to color the edge between a node with 2 degrees and its succeeding node blue.** For example, the edge color of `('HFECrzYDpgbS5EmTBtj2zQ', 'Xj0O2l0bp633ebmG468aZw')` should be in blue. Could anyone help me out?

[image]

Comment: Could you post the source code?

Comment: @BrandonWang I have edited the question into a simpler scenario, could you take a look?

Comment: You need to use give `edge_color` in your `nx.draw` fucntion.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510095/python-coloring-specific-edges-in-networkx might be helpful. Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120957/python-networkx-mark-edges-by-coloring-for-graph-drawing?rq=1

Comment: @Tai it's a little more redundant than just using 'edge_color()', since first I need to select edges between a node that is 2 degree and its succeeding node.

Comment: Edited your question and hope someone can help you with that.

Comment: Since this is a directed network, what do you mean by "a node that is 2 degree"? Do you mean a node that has an out-degree of 2, in-degree of 2, or total in- and out-degree of two?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a list of colors to the `edge_color` parameter of your `nx.draw()` method. Now, one way to create the list, given an if-else conditional, is as follows:

```
edge_colors = ['color1' if your_condition else 'color2' for e in G.edges]
```

Here, `e` is the an edge, which in [NetworkX v2.1](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/), is just a tuple `(node1, node2)`. You can use the edge itself or each node in the tuple for conditioning.

In your specific case (if I understood you correctly), it would be:

```
edge_colors = ['blue' if DG.degree[e[0]] == 2 else 'black' for e in DG.edges]
```

Then, you just pass this to the `edge_color` parameter. In your case:

```
nx.draw(DG, pos=pos,  arrows=False, edge_color=edge_colors, node_color='black', width=0.7, alpha=0.9)
```